# Can't find all roots in Newtons-Raphson method (Python)

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

The code that I am using work fine for 2 of the 4 roots of my function, I can't seem to make it work for all 4 roots.

```
from numpy import *
from scipy import *
import numpy as np

def f(x):
    return np.arctan(2*(x - 1)) - np.log(abs(x))

def fprime(x):
    return (16/5)*((x - (5/4))**2)-1



def newtonRaphson(x0,e=1.0e-3):
    for val in range(1, 15):
        dx = - f(x0)/fprime(x0)
        print(dx)
        x0 = x0 + dx
        if abs(dx) < e: 
            return x0,val
    print('Too many iterations\n')

root,numIter = newtonRaphson(-1.0)
print ('Root =',root)
print ('Number of iterations =',numIter)
```

The roots should be -0.300098, 0.425412, 1, 4.09946

When I use -1.0, I get the root -0.300098, and when I use 1, I get the root 1, but I can't seem to get the other 2 roots. What do I need to do to my code to get it to work? Thanks

Comment: You return the value from your function after it finds the first root. That's the first problem - your function terminates as soon as it finds the first root. Second is you probably want to rewrite this code to supply as many initial guesses as there are roots and solve separately for each of them.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is good, the problem is your function - it's too complicated for the method. You can either use a more sophisticated root finding method or you can decrease `dx` and increase the number of iterations. For instance you can use `dx/1000` and 1.5 million maximum iterations. That will give you all the roots. For roots 1 and 4.0996 you will have to use a very close guess. The code works well for simple functions like simple quadratic functions.